# Count api calls with token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, token

Im trying to create an api that requires tokens for use. Each time a page is called i check if the token exist with this before_filter in the controller:

```
            def restrict_access_token
                authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
                    ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
                end
            end
```

When an apikey is found I want to increment a count column in the ApiKey table.

I was looking for a callback in the model that triggers when the apikey is found but that don't seems to work in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, you need to override `exists?` method

```
def self.exists?(conditions = :none)
  if super
    ...{YOUR CALLBACK}...
  end
end
```

Update:
I would prefer to customize your method like `find_and_increment(...)`. so in model:

```
def self.find_and_increment(conditions = :none)
  if object = where(conditions).first
    object.increment!(...)
  end
end
```